# How i can find error details from thread id in lucee?

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I want to know about error details against Thread id showing in "siteFolder\WEB-INF\lucee\logs" folder and exception.log file.

have a look error log screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: The error is a Null Pointer Exception.  The information in the screenshot is insufficient for solving the problem.  Try to find the page that was running.

Comment: ok, thanks for responding.

Actually, I have multiple pages on the website, I want to know from where the error is triggering, is there any log file containing that type of information in Lucee?